# Getting date of creation for feature using osm_id

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have download some OpenStreetMap data from Geofabrik GmbH. https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india.html

I need to extract when was the first time each feature was created. E.g., for OSM_ID = 421427136, how could I extract the date when it was added to OSM? Optionally, also when it was last modified.

[image]

Any language / tools would be okay - but a python programming based answer would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the https://overpass-turbo.eu/ Wizard and some adjustments, I managed to create a query for retrieving the metadata of a specific `way` (*i.e.* `id:421427136`):

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“id:421427136”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “id:421427136”
  way(421427136);
);
// print results
out meta; // this will get you the metadata
```

The JSON this query returns is the following:

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.55.1011 6c2efc30",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2020-02-06T15:05:01Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "way",
  "id": 421427136,
  "timestamp": "2016-05-28T04:57:05Z",
  "version": 1,
  "changeset": 39617700,
  "user": "kalekhya",
  "uid": 3954285,
  "nodes": [
    4211811580,
    4211811578,
    4211811577
  ],
  "tags": {
    "highway": "residential"
  }
}

  ]
}
```

As you can see, there is a timestamp for the element. According to @mmd,

> the timestamp *always* refers to the last modified date. It corresponds to the creation timestamp only in case the version is 1.

---

As Python is concerned, you can use `requests` to execute this query from a program.

```py
import requests


overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
feat_id = 421427136
query = f'[out:json][timeout:25];(way({feat_id}););out meta;'

r = requests.get(overpass_url, params={'data': query})
```

If you take a look at `r.json()` you will see that it is the same JSON (of course after beautifying it):

```
{
    'version': 0.6,
    'generator': 'Overpass API 0.7.55.1011 6c2efc30',
    'osm3s': {
        'timestamp_osm_base': '2020-02-06T14:40:02Z',
        'copyright': 'The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.'
    },
    'elements': [{
        'type': 'way',
        'id': 421427136,
        'timestamp': '2016-05-28T04:57:05Z',
        'version': 1,
        'changeset': 39617700,
        'user': 'kalekhya',
        'uid': 3954285,
        'nodes': [4211811580, 4211811578, 4211811577],
        'tags': {
            'highway': 'residential'
        }
    }]
}
```

To access the timestamp of the element (*i.e.* the `way`) you would simply do this:

```py
element = r.json()['elements'][0]
if element['version'] == 1:
    creation_date = element['timestamp']  # '2016-05-28T04:57:05Z'
else:
    modification_date = element['timestamp']
```

Note that the Overpass API returns only one timestamp and you will have to evaluate if it is the creation date or the last modification date. @mmd suggests looking at the OSM API if you need to return the creation timestamp always.

Do not forget to take a look at the `datetime` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) if you are planning to parse dates.

Comment: Ids are not unique across nodes, ways and relations, i.e. you need to always specify if you look at node 123, way 123 or relaiton 123. The number "123" per se has no meaning at all. Querying for nodes, ways and relations with a given Id is not a very reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Also, the timestamp _always_ refers to the last modified date. It corresponds to the creation timestmap only in case the version is 1.

Comment: Nice, will edit my answer. Is there any way of getting the creation timestamp for cases where this returns the last modified date?

Comment: No, this isn't supported by Overpass API. You need to look at OSM API instead (which may be used for editing OpenStreetMap only, though).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and supporting comments. The answer is pretty much what I was looking for. But, now I am confused as to how do I know which OSM ID is node, way or relation? The data from Geofabrik did not specify any such thing. I read the difference between them (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) and it seems to me that all the roads that I have downloaded would be "way". Could you guide me a bit more.

Comment: Writing only `way(421427136);` (instead of adding, for example, `node(421427136);`) in the Overpass query will ensure you only get a `way` element in the response. If you are sure that all the elements that you want to get the creation date for are `way` elements, use the query I wrote in my example.

Comment: @PKG: we cannot answer your question. You didn't mention what files exactly you've downloaded from Geofabrik, nor did you describe how you loaded them into QGis. In case you're using Shapefiles, there isn't an exact match to an OSM object in every case, because the data is pre-processed.